# javascript function changeimage()

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with a function that's should change the image when I click on the button it pass directly from the first image to the last image. What is wrong in my code ?

```js
<script language="javascript">
    function changeImage() {

        if (document.getElementById("image").src == "1.jpg") 
        {
            document.getElementById("image").src = "2.jpg";
        }
        else   if (document.getElementById("image").src == "2.jpg") 
        {
            document.getElementById("image").src = "3.jpg";
        }
  

    }
</script>
```

Comment: How do your HTML look like?

Comment: Do some basic debugging. Add `alert(document.getElementById("image").src)` to the top and see what you are actually comparing your strings to.

Comment: Off-topic: The `language` attribute has been deprecated for a long time, and should not be used. use `type` instead.

Comment: un-clear question and using deprecated script...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing `DOMNode.src` will return the full path to the image:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = 'a.png';
console.log(img.src); // https://example.com/a.png
console.log(img.getAttribute('src')) // a.png
```

Your `changeImage` function can be rewritten as:

```
function changeImage() {
    var image = document.getElementById("image");
    var src = image.getAttribute('src');
    if (src == "1.jpg") {
        image.src = "2.jpg";
    }
    else if (src == "2.jpg") {
        image.src = "3.jpg";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use something like this:

```
function changeImage() {
  var image = document.getElementById("image");
  var src = image.getAttribute("src");

  if (src === "1.jpg") {
    image.src = "2.jpg";
  } else if (src === "2.jpg") {
    image.src = "3.jpg";
  }     
}
```

Give me a shout if it works.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<html>
<head>

<script language="javascript">
    function changeImage() {

        if (document.getElementById("image").src == "1.jpg") 
        {
            document.getElementById("image").src = "2.jpg";
        }
        else   (document.getElementById("image").src == "2.jpg") 
        {
            document.getElementById("image").src = "3.jpg";
        }
  

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img id="image" src="1.jpg" ><br><br></img>
<button id="clickme" onclick="changeImage();"> : pass </button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<img>` tag is self-closing, so you shouldn't write `<img id="image" src="1.jpg" ><br><br></img>`. Instead, use `<img id="image" src="1.jpg">`.